# Use AWS ALB on docker swarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm, amazon-elb

Does anyone tried to configure AWS Application load balancing to docker swarm running on EC2 instances not on EC2 CS, because most documentation shows only Docker for AWS, I saw some post that you must include the ARN on the label but I think it's still not working. Also, the DNS on the load balancer does not show the nginx even though port 80 is already allowed on our security group

This is the command I used when running the services,

```
docker service create   --name=test  --publish 80:80 --publish  444:80 --constraint 'engine.labels.serverType == dev' --replicas=2 --label com.docker.aws.lb.arn="<arn-value-here>" nginx:alpine
```

Current Setup:

- EC2 instance
- Subnet included on the loadbalancer

Any insights will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes I have tried. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Currently, we are using docker swarm on our EC2 and we have a Java Application that is running as a service, Could you help me on how can I use the Aws ALB as the load balancer for the Java Application? Most forums shows only EC2 CS and cloudformation that's why I'm lost on how can I use the ALB.

Comment: I suppose EC2 instances running swarm should have assigned IAM role with permissions allowing updating ELB configuration. @user8897710, did you've solved the issue?